# Why is Math.pow() (sometimes) not equal to ** in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8, ecmascript-2016

I've just discovered the ECMAScript 7 feature `a**b` as an alternative for `Math.pow(a,b)` ([MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation_(**))) and came across a discussion in [that post](http://www.2ality.com/2016/02/exponentiation-operator.html#comment-2946471782), in which they apparently behave differently. I've tested it in Chrome 55 and can confirm that the results differ.

`Math.pow(99,99)` returns `3.697296376497263e+197`

whereas

`99**99` returns `3.697296376497268e+197`

So logging the difference `Math.pow(99,99) - 99**99` results in `-5.311379928167671e+182`.

So far it could be said, that it's simply another implementation, but wrapping it in a function behaves different again:

```
function diff(x) {
  return Math.pow(x,x) - x**x;
}
```

calling `diff(99)` returns `0`.

Why is that happening?

As [xszaboj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3454771/xszaboj) pointed out, this can be narrowed down to this problem:

```
var x = 99;
x**x - 99**99; // Returns -5.311379928167671e+182
```

Comment: It sounds like someone rewrote the algorithm they used, and a [floating point error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1458633/1195056) was found. Numbers are hard...

Comment: @krillgar sounds reasonable, but why isn't that same error happening in a function then?

Comment: It's not necessarily a function. I just tried with the values hard coded inside a function, and get the same difference (Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m console). However, using a variable does return 0. Perhaps it's something with being passed as a variable results in another imprecise floating point error? I'm grasping at straws though with that.

Comment: If that matters, my [calculator](http://speedcrunch.org/) produces the same output than `Math.pow()`.

Comment: Firefox 45.1 does not recognize the `**` operator.

Comment: @AndersonPimentel The MDN link points to a [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks! Missed that.

Comment: That's an interesting catch `**` is giving more correct answer. According to standard JS guarantees precision up to 2 ^ 53 − 2. So if number is no more taht this - we could expect any behavior.

But still I believe that different results is bug in v8

Comment: @Andrey I could get that the implementation just differs due to the nature of working with pretty huge numbers but what I can't wrap my head around is, why that error does not occur when the value is passed in a function as variable. Either the error in `**` doesn't occur or the same error suddenly comes up in `Math.pow`

Comment: difference is between this two: var x = 99; x * * x ; and 99 * * 99. Or function diff(x) {
  return 99 * * 99 - (x * * x);
}; diff(99). Sorry for spacing, Comment filters two stars :(

Comment: @xszaboj Wrap your code in backticks to fix the formatting. `\`like this\``

Comment: @JamesThorpe Test: `function diff(x) { return 99 ** 99 - (x ** x); }; diff(99)`

Comment: @xszaboj put code into backticks [`\`likethis\``](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to make it readable and also avoid the bold/italic problem

Comment: Why do they even add `**` as an alternative for `Math.pow`? Yet another unnecessary syntax that most people will not know and cause unreadable code

Answer (score 128, accepted):

`99**99` is [evaluated at compile time](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/875165ea170feda50cec69193b50758b1d8d2de8/src/parsing/parser.cc#L306) ("constant folding"), and the compiler's [`pow` routine](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/875165ea170feda50cec69193b50758b1d8d2de8/src/utils.h#L237) is different from the [runtime one](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/875165ea170feda50cec69193b50758b1d8d2de8/src/builtins/builtins-math.cc#L396). When evaluating `**` at run time, results are identical with `Math.pow` — no wonder since `**` is actually [compiled](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/875165ea170feda50cec69193b50758b1d8d2de8/src/parsing/parser.cc#L4026) to a `Math.pow` call:

```js
console.log(99**99);           // 3.697296376497268e+197
a = 99, b = 99;
console.log(a**b);             // 3.697296376497263e+197
console.log(Math.pow(99, 99)); // 3.697296376497263e+197
```

Actually

<sup>99<sup>99</sup>=369729637649726772657187905628805440595668764281741102430259972423552570455277523421410650010128232727940978889548326540119429996769494359451621570193644014418071060667659301384999779999159200499899</sup>

so the first result is a better approximation, still such a discrepancy between constant- and dynamic expressions shouldn't take place.

This behavior looks like a bug in V8. It [has been reported](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=5848) and will hopefully get fixed soon.

Comment: So it's basically JS trying to improve performance with computing `99**99` beforehand? Could this be considered a bug, since `Math.pow` creates the same output for numbers and variables and `**` doesn't?

Comment: @ThomasAltmann: `Math.row` is always runtime, const folding can only be done for operators. Yes, it's definitely a bug.

Comment: A bug [has been logged](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=5848), by the looks of things by the OP here.

Comment: I'm using MS Edge, and all 3 results are the same: `3.697296376497263e+197`, `3.697296376497263e+197`, and `3.697296376497263e+197` respectively. It's most definitely a Chrome bug.

Comment: @ThomasAltmann if constant folding produces a *worse* value than the runtime impl then it's a bug. If it produces a *better* value than the runtime then it might or might not be considered a bug. In this case, it's better — the correct value is "... 26772...", constant folding produces "...268" (correctly rounded), and the runtime produces "...263" (off by 4+ units in the last place).

Comment: @hobbs If it's producing a different result than the runtime, then it's most definitely a compiler optimisation bug, better value or not.  Whether the runtime itself could be improved to a better value (and therefore also the compiler optimisation) is a separate issue.

Comment: Your snippet is broken, it seems.  `"message": "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '*'",` (I can't into JavaScript, sorry, no idea what's wrong)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: `**` only works in recent Chrome/FF (52+)